# How to add background-sync-plugin to workbox-build

Tags: node.js, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I've got question regarding workbox and create-react-app v2.
I'm using workbox-build to generate custom service worker, and there is a problem with injecting

```
const backgroundSync = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('ticketsQueue', {
  maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours
});


const buildSW = () =>
  workboxBuild.generateSW({
    globDirectory: 'build',
   // importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
    globPatterns: ['**/*.{json,ico,html,js,css,woff2,woff,png,svg}'],
    globIgnores: ['asset-manifest.json'],
    skipWaiting: true,
    clientsClaim: true,
    swDest: 'build/sw.js',
    navigateFallback: 'index.html',
    directoryIndex: 'index.html',
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: new RegExp(`^${apiUrl}/tickets/create`),
        handler: 'networkOnly',
        options: {
          plugins: [
            backgroundSync
          ]
        },
        method: 'POST'
      },
     ]
  });

buildSW();
```

When I try too execute buildSW() with nodejs it gives a reference error.
ReferenceError: workbox is not defined
How to include it? Or is there any other way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

First, you can switch to using [`injectManifest` mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build#injectmanifest_mode), and have complete control over your service worker, relying on the build tool to just inject the array of files to precache.

Second, there is a shortcut `options` property that simplifies adding in the background sync plugin. The config looks something like:

```
runtimeCaching: [{
  // Match any same-origin request that contains 'api'.
  urlPattern: /api/,
  handler: 'networkOnly',
  options: {
    backgroundSync: {
      name: 'my-queue-name',
      options: {
        maxRetentionTime: 60 * 60,
      },
    },
  },
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser. Last week I didn't saw this option in documentation :) However after trying this out I noticed that generated Service Worker don't pass callbacks functions for queueDidReplay if you put it in options

Answer (score 0):

Well, after playing around with the url pattern, i realised that this is where I had erred. One fix, in the URL pattern and i saw indexeddb queue getting created and background sync starting to happen as expected. Thanks a lot